# In MS Access combo box,how to use form value as where class

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am using following query in combo box for display data from table based on form text box field as parameter but combo box is not displaying data. Please note that itemid field in main item table is string.

```
SELECT [Item].[ID], [Item].[ItemCode], [Item].[ItemName], [Item].[Price_USD], 
[Item].[Price_GBP], [Item].[Price_THB], [Item].[Price_AED], [Item].[Price_AED_VAT], 
[Item].[Price_SAR], [Item].[Price_SAR_WHT], [Item].[Hogan_Cost_USD] 
FROM Item WHERE [ItemCode]='Forms!Order_Detail subform!itemid';
```

Comment: Don't enclose reference to form textbox in apostrophes. If you used query builder to help get correct SQL construction, those apostrophes should not be there. Use apostrophes if you hard-code an actual value: `[ItemCode]='abc'`.

Comment: without apostrophes following error is appear " Syntex error missing operator in query operation '((([ItemCode])=Forms!Oder_Derail subform!itemid))'

Comment: Probably because of space in **Order_Detail subform**. Enclose form name in [ ]. Again, the query builder should do that for you. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: now error is enter value for parameter Forms!Order_detail subform!itemid,i think still system is not properly reading itemid field value from sub form.

Comment: Oh crud, referencing a subform must first reference parent form. `Forms!parentformname!subformcontainername.Form!itemid`. I always name container different from the form it holds, such as `ctrDetail`. But if this combobox is on the subform and you have this SQL statement in the RowSource property, just try `=[itemid]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a query object, then must reference subform through parent form and subform container control. I always name container different from the object it holds, such as ctrDetails
`WHERE [ItemCode]=Forms!parentformname!ctrDetails.Form!itemid;`

If this SQL statement is directly in combobox RowSource and combobox is on subform along with the textbox, just reference textbox directly. I always name controls different from fields, such as tbxIC:
`WHERE [ItemCode]=[tbxIC]`

Are you pulling in every field from Item table? If so, could shorten the SQL with wildcard:
`SELECT * FROM Item WHERE [ItemCode]=[tbxIC];`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed feedback,one last query regarding above issue.Is this possible that i will use field specific where class in my query e.g if in item table field name are price_usd,price_gbp then i will query where tablename.fieldname like "*GBP"

Comment: Field name cannot be dynamic in query object or SQL statement in RowSource. With that table structure, would have to use VBA to build SQL and set combobox RowSource property. Post another question if you need more help with that. If instead of 2 price fields, there was Price and CurrencyType, then: `WHERE CurrencyType = [tbxCT]`.